# eclipse ide svn network connection using tor

Tags: eclipse, svn, tor

I am working on a project where we use a remote subversion server. The server uses the port 9090. I can access the server from my home PC. However, when I am in school, I don't have access probably due to the firewall used in here. So, I used a proxy server "Tor" and I managed to successfully connect to the server from the Tor browser.

Now Problem is how can I configure Eclipse to connect to the SVN server through the Tor proxy.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you understand what Tor is meant to be used for? It's not an appropriate solution for what you're doing.

Comment: So what's the alternative in your opinion?

Comment: Use a proper VPN, or talk to your school's network admins about opening the firewall port. Or run the server on a standard port so that the firewall doesn't have to be opened.

Answer (score 0):

You need http proxy for eclipse try [FreeGate](http://us.dongtaiwang.com/loc/download.en.php) proxy (with wine if the operating system is Linux)